# When to initialize properties in Java EE webapp?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jax-rs

We are having a JAX-RS based webapp & it would be requiring to read some configuration from the properties file. I have written a ConfigurationProvider helper class which loads these properties. This class is going to be used in multiple classes. My question is when & where should the ConfigurationProvider should be initialized?

```
    public class ConfigurationProvider {
private static Properties properties;
private static ConfigurationProvider config;
private static final String XYZ_PROPERTIES = "xyz.properties";

static {
    config = new ConfigurationProvider();
}

private ConfigurationProvider() {
    try {
        InputStream in = this.getClass().getClassLoader().
                getResourceAsStream(XYZ_PROPERTIES);
        properties = new Properties();
        properties.load(in);
    } catch(IOException ie) {
        ie.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static ConfigurationProvider getInstance() {
    return config;
}

public String get(String propname) {
    return properties.getProperty(propname, null);
}
    }
```

Regards

Comment: Create a Singleton of `ConfigurationProvider` if you don't want to always instantiate it and have a cache of `ResourceBundle` based on their `Locale`. That way you don't have to always reload properties file every time you need it.

Comment: @BuhakeSindi, I guess ConfigurationProvider is already singleton. I am initializing config in static block & there is a private constructor. Only way to get instance is from getInstance method.

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html

You can use a PostConstruct method in JAX-RS resource class.

```
@PostConstruct
private void init() {
   /initialize...
}
```

However, I am not sure application defining a singleton is a good idea. You could use an ApplicationScoped bean instead, if you are using a Java EE environment.

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/enterprise/context/ApplicationScoped.html

Comment: Will this allows to access the ConfigurationProvider in the helpers method as well apart from the resource class?

Comment: I am not sure, if applications defining singletons in a Java EE server is a good practice. What you could do is use an ApplicationScoped bean instead. I will edit my answer to reflect that.

Comment: I don't think ApplicationScoped is applicable for Java EE 5. What do we have for EE5